# How can I create a user tagging system in a contentEditable div?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a user input (content Editable div) for a chat where someone can write something and tag someone like hello @user32. My problem is when I type @ list is open and tag but when I write some text and press enter then type @ list is not shown. Position is same and carry last word with @.

```
<script>
function contentTag(e,t){
        let sentence = t.value;
        //alert(sentence);
    var endpos = t.selectionEnd;
    var result = /\S+$/.exec(sentence.slice(0, endpos));
    var lastWord = result ? result[0] : null;
    //console.log(endpos);
         if ((lastWord && lastWord.indexOf("@") == 0) ? lastWord :"") {
             let name = lastWord.replace('@', '');
             // $("#result").hide();

             $.ajax({

                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '<?php echo $link->link('ajax', backend); ?>',
                 data: "Name=" + name,
                 success: function(data) {
                     //  alert(data);
                     var test = data;
                     if (test != undefined) {
                         $("#result").show();
                         $("#result").html(data);
                     }
                     if (test == ' ') {
                         $("#result").hide();
                     }
                 }

             })

         } else {
             $("#result").hide();
         }
     });
</script>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><div contenteditable="true"  id="contentive" onkeyup="contentTag(event,this)" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this an HTML problem, a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I want to make a function which works like selectionEnd,    selectionEnd is not work in contestable div.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I have no clue what you  mean by "selectionEnd is not work in contestable div". Also, the code you've shared misses HTML output and `contentTag` is not called anywhere

Comment: selectionEnd  is return cursor potion in textarea , I am using contenteditable div  I want to   cursor position.